# Making drawings already made inside canvas smaller/scale

Tags: javascript, web, canvas, graph, scaling

Ive been stuck on this problem for a very long time now and I cant find anything online, Im drawing a graph inside a canvas in javascript and I want so that when the graph goes outside the canvas width/heigh it scales to make everything inside smaler to include the stuff that gets drawn outside the total size of the canvas.

Everything I find online is for scaling the canvas but it dosent change the size of the things already drawn. I would GREATLY appreciate anything that could help.

Comment: I'm afraid your question alone isn't enough to get a decent answer. Please provide some code, that showcases your issue.